# Javascript Array multidimensional pushing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, push

I'm tryin to convert the column to the row :

```
 var  input = [
    ["aaa","111","zzz"],
    ["bbb","222","xxx"],
    ["ccc","333","yyy"]
    ];
```

to this :

```
input = [
["aaa","bbb","ccc"],
["111","222","333"],
["zzz","xxx","yyy"],
];
```

here what i have done, why the output[j].push(input [i][j]);
didnt work ?, the output[j] is all I need ... 'j' is looping right ?
I did manual, it works , I did all the research but my brain not good enough yet, so can anyone explain it ?? im a total newbie. I need someone to find my mistake since I always thinkin if my logic actually  true but why it'snot workin . it make me confused and not able to learn another way.

```
function dataHandling(){

   var output = []; 

    for (var i=0; i < input.length  ; i++){ 
      output.push([]);
      //console.log(i)
      for (var j =0; j < input[i].length ; j++){
      output[j].push(input[i][j]);
 }

   }
 console.log(output);

}

 // console.log(len2);


     var input = [
["aaa","111","zzz"],
["bbb","222","xxx"],
["ccc","333","yyy"]
];

dataHandling(input);
```

EDIT : can this apply without passing the parameter ? and keep dataHandling() empty,  but thanks for the that answers tho, im tryin to learn it.

EDIT 2 : meanwhile >> output[i].push(input[j][i]);   givin me the answer, yeah it's work but
if I change unsymmetric matrix
if I change the input to:

```
var input = [
                ["0001", "Roman Alamsyah", "Bandar Lampung", "21/05/1989", "Membaca"],
                ["0002", "Dika Sembiring", "Medan", "10/10/1992", "Bermain Gitar"],
                ["0003", "Winona", "Ambon", "25/12/1965", "Memasak"],
                ["0004", "Bintang Senjaya", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Berkebun"]
];
```

why it's not workin at all ? error in jsbin.

Comment: This is called transposing a matrix btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solutions of [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588725/5630582) and [Nenad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588728/5630582) are very good solutions, I'd like to point out a little problem in your algorithm: your `ouput[j].push()` is not doing what you're expecting.

Because `j` is the index inside the sub-array, you will try to push things in other things that does not exists. `output` will contain only one element, the one you pushed in the beginning of your loop, but you'll try to push something to all 3 elements of `output`. So you'll call `push()` on something `undefined`, resulting in an **`Error`** (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` precisely).

Instead of pushing the elements in that order, I propose you to do it in another way, where you handle first the sub-array of `output`, instead of the sub-array of `input`:

```
function dataHandling(input){
  var output = [];
  for (var i=0; i < input[0].length  ; i++){ 
    output.push([]);
    for (var j =0; j < input.length ; j++)
      output[i].push(input[j][i]);
  }
  console.log(output);
}



var input = [
    ["aaa","111","zzz"],
    ["bbb","222","xxx"],
    ["ccc","333","yyy"]
  ];

dataHandling(input);
```

In fact it looks a lot like [J-Mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589072/5630582) answer, but with a little fix on the indices of the two `for` loops. That function assume that all sub-arrays are of the same length.

### EDIT:

#### About the parameter

In fact you don't need it, if the variable is available in the scope, but I don't remember if it's in the declaration scope, or execution scope. Anyway, not passing it as parameter is a side effect, and it can lead to weird bugs, so I discourage you from using it. At the beginning, it's really tempting to use a lot of global variables (read: variables not passed as parameters), but avoid it as much as possible.

#### About the new input

I fixed the code above, and tested it, it was the `input[i].length` which failed, because the sub-arrays were longer than the `input`, so just replace the `i` by a `0`.

Comment: if the output.push([]); inside the sub-array then output[j] will work right . but  I'm still hard to understand  it all  ..."you will try to push things in other things that does not exists."  since in my mind  J is count up in sub-array

Comment: wont work with unsymmetric matrix ?

Comment: It will work, but only if it is a real matrix, which JavaScript doesn't enforce.
Just iterate over your loop, on a paper, and you'll see that in the second for loop, you'll do `ouput[0].push(..)`, `ouput[1].push(..)`, `ouput[2].push(..)`, while `output` will only be of the form: `output = [ [] ]`. `output` won't have anything in indices 1 and 2.That's because `j` iterates over the sub-array, rather than the already existant but not complete `output`.

Comment: But I think that while it's important to understand what are my fixes, IMO the solutions of [Nina](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40588725/5630582) and [Nenad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40588728/5630582) are way better.

Comment: thank you sir, yeah they're better but not the one i want right now :) , im still newbie and it looks so challenging.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two nested [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) lopps and assign the pivot values to the changed indices.

```js
var input = [["aaa", "111", "zzz"], ["bbb", "222", "xxx"], ["ccc", "333", "yyy"]],
    output=[];

input.forEach(function (a, j) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i) {
        output[i] = output[i] || [];
        output[i][j] = b;
    });
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `map()` you just need to return `input[c][i]` where

1. `c` is index of each element in inner array so 0, 1, 2
2. `i` is index of current inner array so in each iteration of elements in inner array it will be 0 then 1 etc ...

```js
var input = [
  ["aaa", "111", "zzz"],
  ["bbb", "222", "xxx"],
  ["ccc", "333", "yyy"]
];

var result = input.map(function(arr, i) {
  return arr.map(function(e, c) {
    return input[c][i]
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Your could do it like this if you want to use two `for` loops.

```js
var input = [
  ["aaa", "111", "zzz"],
  ["bbb", "222", "xxx"],
  ["ccc", "333", "yyy"]
];

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var ar = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
    ar.push(input[j][i]);
  }
  output.push(ar)
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had modified your solution. Please try it!!

```
  var input = [["aaa", "111", "zzz"],
                ["bbb", "222", "xxx"],
                ["ccc", "333", "yyy"]
    ];

    function dataHandling() {           
        var output = [];        

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length  ; i++) {                
            output[i] = [];                
            for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length ; j++) {                    
                output[i][j] = input[j][i];
            }
        }        
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
```